# How to create a html form associated with this code

Tags: php, mysqli

I have piece of code (imageupload.php) below where the php is suppose to upload a file into the server and insert data into the database.

```
 <?php 
    /* check connection */ 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
        die(); 
    } 

    $result = 0; 

    //UPLOAD IMAGE FILE 

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]); 

    $result = 1; 

    //INSERT INTO IMAGE DATABASE TABLE 

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)"; 

    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) { 
        // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
    } 

    //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable 
    $insert->bind_param("s", $img); 

    //Assign the variable 
    $img = 'ImageFiles/' . $_FILES['fileImage']['name']; 

    $insert->execute(); 

    $insertimagequestion->execute(); 

    //IF ANY ERROR WHILE INSERTING DATA INTO EITHER OF THE TABLES 
    if ($insert->errno) { 
      // Handle query error here 
    } 

    $insert->close(); 

    }
    ?>
```

But I want to create html form to associate with this but I have never created a file input in html. Does anybody know how to create the html form that can be associated with this?

I want a html code so that I can test the code above and then be able to test for any errors if there are any.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make HTML form as below:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/upload.php"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="fileImage" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```